# Wordsearch puzzle method

Tags: java

I'm coding a wordsearch puzzle and I need to write a helper method called `isHorizontalSpaceFree()`.

The method should check whether (starting from aRow and aCol) there is enough free space to insert word into `letterGrid(left to right)`. If there is enough space, the method should return true, otherwise it should return false.

I need the method to return an out of bounds exception if the word length exceeds the end of the array as well.

Here is my code so far

```
   public boolean isHorizontalSpaceFree(int aRow, int aCol, String word)
   {
      boolean result = true;
      if (aCol < NUMBER_COLS - word.length())
      {
        int i = aCol;
        while (aCol < NUMBER_COLS - word.length())
        {
          if (letterGrid[aRow][aCol] != BLANK_ELEMENT
              || aCol > NUMBER_COLS - word.length())
          {
            result = false;
          }
          aCol++;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        result = false;
      }
      return result;
    }
```

I hope it's not too far away.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Do you have a question?  3)  Does the code do what you want?  If it has bugs, answer these questions.  4) What do you expect the output to be?  5) What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I'm assuming you want the method to return true if:

1. There are enough remaining columns between `aCol` and `NUMBER_COL` to fit the word
2. Each of cells in `aRow` between `aCol` and `aCol + word.length()` are `BLANK_ELEMENT`s

Given the above, the following should work:

```
public boolean isHorizontalSpaceFree(final int aRow, final int aCol, final String word) {
    // Asserts that the word will fit in the remaining cells
    if(aCol + word.length() > NUMBER_COLS) {
        return false;
    }
    // Asserts that each cell in the row aRow between aCol and aCol+word.length() are empty
    char[] columns = letterGrid[aRow] // I've assume your grid is made up of chars
    for(int i = aCol; i < aCol + word.length(); i++) {
        if(columns[i] != BLANK_ELEMENT) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // There is enough remaining blank cells to insert the word
    return true;
}
```

Edit: As mentioned in Andreas_D answer, this method shouldn't really be throwing an exception, rather returning just `true` and `false`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the code insight - it works perfectly. I was trying to use a while loop - big up this forum by the way!

Comment: i will mate - think i need 15 reputation 1st though to up vote

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't throw an Exception if the word is to long, just because that is (probably) not an exceptional condition. You could simply return false, because a word, whose length exceeds a row length, won't fit, the answer to your question "isHorizontalSpaceFree ?" is false.

Consider exceptions for the case `word == null` or `word.equals("")` though:

```
if (word == null || word.equals("")) {
   // a null reference or an empty String are not allowed
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Word must not be null or empty");
}
if (word.length() > NUMBER_COLS) {
   // a word that is longer then row does not fit (trivial case)
   return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks - yes i suppose all i needed was a false if the word doesn't fit ;)